# Capture all return values from a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I was playing around with delegates and anonymous methods and came across the code below:

```
delegate int IntegerGenerator();
static void Main()
{
    IntegerGenerator numberGenerator;

    numberGenerator = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("returns 7");
        return 7;
    };
    numberGenerator += () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("returns 3");
        return 3;
    };

    // This will always return 3
    var num = numberGenerator();

    Console.WriteLine("Return value: {0}", num);
}
```

I am interested by the returning values from all methods in the Invocation list of the delegate. However it seems as the only value that is given back is from the last method to be attached to the delegate.
A possible workaround is by inputting a collection and just adding the result to it. However that doesn't seem to be the right way to approach this because of the return type of the delegate.

How can I capture all return values from the attached methods in the delegate?

Comment: Why are you joining delegates? You wouln't have this problem if you add delegates to a collection and then invoke each one separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd need to use [`MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) and invoke each delegate separately. For example:

```
List<int> results = numberGenerator.GetInvocationList()
                                   .Cast<IntegerGenerator>()
                                   .Select(x => x())
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Amazing @Jon Skeet. Never heard about that class ;)

Comment: @CarlosLanderas: It's not that it doesn't exist - it's that the compiler wasn't able to infer the return type. Method group conversions in LINQ are fiddly - I can never predict when they're going to work. Using a lambda expression is fine though.

Comment: +1 , By the way, should not the List<Int> be List<IntegerGenerator> ? I get can not implicitely convert.

Comment: @CarlosLanderas: No, because it's getting the *results*. The code I've got now does work. Are you sure you didn't mis-type `x => x()` as `x => x`?

Comment: You are right. I was typing it wrong. How could you pass a parameter inside Select(x => x()) if the delegate would be:    private delegate string StringHandlerDelegate(string s); ?

Comment: @CarlosLanderas: Well what argument would you *want* to pass? If it's always the same, you'd use `Select(x => x("foo"))` for example.

Comment: Yeah, that was my question exactly. You have to use always the same parameter dont you?. Maybe you want to do something like this, but you have to give always the same param:  StringHandlerDelegate delegate1 = StringHandlerDelegateVoid;
            delegate1 += StringHandlerDelegateVoid2;

            List<string> results256 = delegate1.GetInvocationList().Cast<StringHandlerDelegate>().Select(x => x("A")).ToList();

Comment: @JonSkeet: Brilliant solution. I see that this works perfect along with AsParallel()

Comment: @CarlosLanderas, you don't have to give the same param.  For example, `Select(x => x(i++))` would pass in a different value each time.

Comment: @CarlosLanderas: No, you don't have to always give the same argument. You could use a random number generator for example (to get a potentially different input every time), or whatever you want.